# Img tag causes output panel to not display

Tags: html, richfaces, ajax4jsf

In the code below there are two a4j:output panels. I added in the  the img tag at the top, but it causes the second outputpanel to not display. If I remove it from the code, everything displays and functions as it should. Know what could be causing this?

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="Display">               
            <img id="Image"
                 src="/document/image"
                 alt="no image">
            </img>
            <br/>
            <a4j:commandButton id="removeButton"
                               action="#{user.remove}"
                           value="Remove "
                           ajaxSingle="true"
                           reRender ="Display"
                           styleClass="delete-button">
            </a4j:commandButton>
```

Comment: What about to use the `h:graphicImage` instead of `img`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the image tag by using

```
<img id="signatureImage"
                 src="/document/image"
                 alt="no image"/>
```

as in, not using

```
 </img>
```

to close it,
fixed the issue.